# Twitter Bootstrap Modal does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Any modal that I am creating using twitter bootstrap fails to appear. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong seeing that I set up a test modal using the code that bootstrap provides and it still doesn't work.

Here is my code (body only):
You need to link to bootstrap.js, bootstrap-modal.js, jquery.js, and bootstrap.css

```
<body>
    <div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;
            </button>
            <h3>Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
                Modal body would go here...
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Show Modal</a>
</body>
```

And here are links to the bootstrap package and jquery that a bootstrap modal needs:
[bootstrap package](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html)
[jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My problem was that I was including both boostrap.js and bootstrap-modal.js. Apparently if you include bootstrap.js you shouldn't also inlclude bootstrap-modal.js because boostrap.js imports all of the javascript plugins that it is compatible with. Something like that. After deleting my boostrap-modal.js script link it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You have to call:

```
<script>
   $('#myModal').modal('show')
</script>
```

After the `</body>` tag. Or if you only want to call it when the user clicks on something:

```
$('#button_id').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
});
```

Comment: My problem was that I was including both boostrap.js and bootstrap-modal.js. Apparently if you include bootstrap.js you shouldn't also inlclude bootstrap-modal.js because boostrap.js imports all of the javascript plugins that it is compatible with. Something like that. After deleting my boostrap-modal.js script link it worked. Thanks though!